# Can GitHub Desktop (or any free Git GUI) be set up with different credentials for each project?

Tags: github, git-config, github-desktop

My department wants to teach students who are new to coding to use Git with GitHub.

`git-push` will by default ask for remote credentials every time. Furthermore, `git-config` can be used without `--global` option to store project-specific `user.name` and `user.email` [[1]](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup#Your-Identity). A typical question is "How can I store my credentials so I don't have to log in each time I push", but for us having to log in each time is the desired behavior.

Since these students are new to coding, we would prefer to use a graphical client like GitHub Desktop. The Git GUIs make it easy to store credentials, but GitHub desktop seems to want to store only one set of credentials, and also specifies that storing name and email "will change your global gitconfig". The problem is that we are working in a kiosk-style computer lab, so any changes to software configuration will be stored for all users, including GitHub account credentials and global config settings.

Therefore can we use GitHub Desktop, or can you recommend another free Git GUI that could accomplish one of the following:

1. Does not require GitHub credentials, asks for credentials on push or other interaction with remote; or
2. Allows multiple GitHub accounts separated into distinct, password-protected profiles.

If you feel this question is on the wrong track and want to propose a different kind of solution than I am considering, please let me know.

### Background

We intend for students to be using this in a kiosk environment, where students keep all their work (project files) on external media.

Comment: Typically the best case scenario would be for each user to have their own home directory. The SSH keys are typically stored at %HOME%/.ssh - on windows 7 this ends up being /Users/username/.ssh. Is there any log-in at all on the kiosk that would allow you to run a script, setting the users home directory?

Comment: Yes, we are far from the best case scenario. That would require students to login in to each workstation with their network IDs. Our college has chosen to have computer labs set up as kiosks, so no login required and shared home directory. Changing that is not an option.

Comment: Maybe you can generate a new ssh key for each user, requiring a passphrase. Then in your .ssh config you add each of these keys with their logins. Then each student would use name@host when performing operations.  See http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/ for one example. Disclaimer: I have never tried doing this.